# T-test - Difference between p-Values of `stats.ttest_1samp`, `stats.ttest_rel` and `stats.ttest_ind`

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, scipy

For a data analysis problem I want to use T-test for verify my hypotheses. For the experiment I take samples of the same population and obtained the following measurement:

$$X := [28, 26, 27, 22, 28, 23, 27]$$
$$Y := [27, 36, 31, 26, 30, 26, 29]$$
$$H_0: \hat x = \hat x$$
$$H_1: \hat x \neq \hat y$$

With `stats.ttest_rel` I can assume dependence between two samples (each measurement comes from the same individual). The obtained p-value is `stats.ttest_rel([28, 26, 27, 22, 28, 23, 27], [27, 36, 31, 26, 30, 26, 29]) = 0.0355`.

With `stats.ttest_ind` I can not assume dependence between two samples (we do not know which measurement comes from which individual). The obtained p-value is `stats.ttest_ind([28, 26, 27, 22, 28, 23, 27], [27, 36, 31, 26, 30, 26, 29]) = 0.0559`.

And finally for `stats.ttest_1samp` I can only compare the second sample with the mean of the first sample. The obtained p-value is `stats.ttest_1samp([29, 30, 31, 27, 26, 26, 36], sum([28, 26, 27, 22, 28, 23, 27]) / 7.0) = 0.0430`.

I understand why the p-value of `stats.ttest_ind` is lower than the p-value of `tats.ttest_rel`. Since we can assume dependence, we have to deal with less randomness. But I do not understand why the p-value of `stats.ttest_1samp` is lower than `stats.ttest_ind`.

Any help would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing the second sample to the mean of the first sample doesn't sense, since you don't know the mean of the first sample for certain. This is a test of the null hypothesis $\mu_y = \text{mean}(x)$, which is not the same as the null hypothesis $\mu_y = \mu_x$.

A paired t-test (`stats.ttest_rel`) is the same as an independent samples t-test on the difference scores for each group:

```py
x = [28, 26, 27, 22, 28, 23, 27]
y = [27, 36, 31, 26, 30, 26, 29]
differences = [y[i] - x[i] for i in range(len(x))]
stats.ttest_1samp(differences, popmean=0)
# 0.0355
```

Comment: "Comparing the second sample to the mean of the first sample doesn't sense, since you don't know the mean of the first sample for certain.". It makes sense for my hypothetical case where the exact data is lost and I only has the mean of the first sample.

Comment: Yes, but it's a test of a different statistical hypothesis, so it wouldn't be expected to produce the same result as your other tests.

Comment: In other words, $\mu_x = \mu_y$ is not the same hypothesis as $\mu_x = \text{mean}(y)$.

Comment: Okay may be my choise of words was a bit bad. I may want to test the hypotheses:
$$H_0: \hat x = \hat x$$
$$H_1: \hat x \neq \hat y$$

I have to choose t-test in this case because of the exercise's specification.

Comment: Also: your code does not compile: TypeError: ttest_1samp() missing 1 required positional argument: 'popmean'

Comment: Normally, $\bar x$ is the sample average of $x$ (that is, `np.mean(x)`), which you know for certain, while $\hat x$ is an uncertain estimate of $\mu_x$, the population mean. In these terms, your one-sample t-test was for $H0: \hat x = \bar y$, which as I've explained, is not the same as $H0: \hat x = \hat y$.

Comment: I see your point and really appericate your help. May I reformulate my question (exactly like the question does)? Assuming I have the measure of second week as 

$$[29, 30, 31, 27, 26, 26, 36]$$


The sum of data from the first week is 181.0. Is the change significant? With this data I think the only statistical test I can use is `ttest_1samp` with $181.0 / 7.0$ as the "population mean" (I know it is not the population mean) and the observations are $[29, 30, 31, 27, 26, 26, 36]$

Comment: Yes, you can certainly test $H0: \mu_y = \frac{181}{7}$, as you've described. It's not the same question as $H0: \mu_y = \mu_x$, though, so it gives you a different p-value.

Comment: Ah, so I have to reformulate my Nullhypothesis for this case. Thanks, I think that answers my question.

$$\text{H}_0:\; \mu=25.8571 \qquad \text{H}_1:\; \mu \neq 25.8571$$

Comment: Please remember to mark the answer above as accepted (and optionally, upvote it).